# How to use Setup variables in Descriptions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-deployment

I have a setup project in VS 2005.

In the UI section I put some textboxes with some variables, that the user should fill-in when installing the application.

[image]
How can I use properties like [VARIABLES] in the fields like the shortcut descriptions?

Answer (score 1):

Your question came up when I was Googling for a list of properties. Seems like the property stuff on MSDN is a bit hidden in the search engines. Of course it helps if you or I found the right name ("property") rather than "variable".

For future reference, the list can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

This should also get you into the "how to use properties in your installer" help.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the shortcut description field is not [formatted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368609%28VS.85%29.aspx), so it doesn't support installer properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371847(VS.85).aspx

A solution is to use a custom action (write your own EXE or DLL) which modifies the shortcut description after installation.